# SiteNavigationElement Schema using JSON

Tags: json, navigation, schema, google-tag-manager, json-ld

I am looking for examples of writing the schema for SiteNavigationElement using JSON but no examples seem to exist. Is there a reason for this? I have found plenty of examples using microdata but we are entering these via Google Tags so they need to be entered via JSON. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Asking for example code is off-topic. -- Did you try converting an example and had a problem? If yes, please show what you have got, and describe your problem.

Comment: I'm not asking for an example. I'm asking if it's possible to write the schema for SiteNavigationElement using JSON.

Comment: Well, in that case you should [edit] your question and make this clear, as currently the very first sentence begins with "I am looking for examples". -- The answer is, by the way, yes -- everything in Schema.org can be expressed in any of the three syntaxes (JSON-LD, Microdata, RDFa).